# "Cannot assign to property: "any" is immutable" error

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimageview, immutability

`tiledViewsStack` contains UIImageViews. I'm trying to give each UIImageView in the array a new center coordinate. Not sure why I'm getting this error for the last line in the for loop... [image]

```
    var tiledViewsStack = [AnyObject]()

    var randLocInt = Int()
    var randLoc = CGPoint()

    for var any in tiledViewsStack
    {
        randLocInt = Int((arc4random()*10) % 9) // 0, --- 8
        randLoc = allCenters[randLocInt].CGPointValue()
        any.center = randLoc
    }
```

Comment: `AnyObject ` and `any.center`?

Comment: Ugh yes, change `var tiledViewsStack = [AnyObject]()` to `var tiledViewsStack = [UIImageView()` thanks @Lumialxk

Comment: I changed `tiledViewsStack = [UIImageView]()` and I won't get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to make `tiledViewsStack` a stack of UIImages, not AnyObjects. Changed `var tiledViewsStack = [AnyObject]()` to `var tiledViewsStack = [UIImageView]()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use **Anyobject**, you are using a **protocol**.

It can be an istance of any type. 
So **AnyObject** can represent an Int, a Float, a String, a UIView, anything.

The array **[AnyObject]** is a nonspecific type to represent any type of class. In you code you initialize an always immutable array, and when you try to modify each element you get the error..

The correct way to declare and initialize a type of this array is:

```
var genericTypeArray : [AnyObject] = [1, true, 1.2, "hello"]
```

For you code, you must change :

```
var tiledViewsStack = [AnyObject]()
```

with a code like my example up, or you modify AnyObject class with a specified class like UIImageView as recommended in comments.