# Disable an array of UIButtons and UITextFields

Tags: ios, swift

What I'm trying to achieve is to disable all my elements on my login screen once the user has pressed the login button. I have created a simple function which keeps an array of all the elements that should be disabled.

```
func disableElements() {
    let elements: [AnyObject] = [usernameInput, passwordInput, loginBtn]

    for element in elements {
        element.isEnabled = false // ERROR: Cannot assign to property: 'element' is a 'let' constant
    }
}
```

I have found a similar question (["Cannot assign to property: "any" is immutable" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36525393/cannot-assign-to-property-any-is-immutable-error)) where the OP was able to just change the array type from `AnyObject` to `UIImageView`, but what if there are different types in the array (like in my case `UITextField`s and `UIButton`s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where he was able to just change the array type from AnyObject to UIImageView, but what if there are different types in the array (like in my case UITextFields and UIButtons

Well, if there are different types of stuff in an array, you just need to find the *nearest common ancestor* of all the types. By common ancestor, I mean the superclass that both classes inherit from.

In this case, you have `UITextField` and `UIButton`. Their nearest ancestor is `UIControl`, which has the `isEnabled` property.

[image]

Therefore, you should use `UIControl` as the type of the array.

```
func disableElements() {
    let elements: [UIControl] = [usernameInput, passwordInput, loginBtn]

    elements.forEach { $0.isEnabled = false }
}
```

Here are the "Relationships" section for `UIButton` and `UITextField`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton#relationships

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield#relationships

Answer (score 2):

The `isEnabled` property is from `UIControl`. Both `UIButton` and `UITextField` extend `UIControl`. So make your array an array of `UIControl` instead of an array of `AnyObject`.

```
func disableElements() {
    let elements: [UIControl] = [usernameInput, passwordInput, loginBtn]

    for element in elements {
        element.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean, ie: `fileprivate var allowUserToInteractWithElements = true`, and when the login button is pressed set this to false.

In your IBAction for your button, and in the UITextfieldShouldBeginEditing delegate method, use this boolean as conditional.  This is a better way to handle disabling of buttons/textfields in my opinion.

Ex:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if (allowUserToInteractWithElements) {
    //Do action
    }
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if (allowUserToInteractWithElements) {
        return false
    }else{
        return true
    }
}
```